# If $\operatorname{rank}(A)=k$, can we say something about $\operatorname{rank}(AA^t)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ a $n\times m$ matrix such that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=k$, 
can we say something about  $\operatorname{rank}(AA^t)$?

It's like: [If $\operatorname{rank}(A)=m$, can we say anything about $\operatorname{rank}(AA^t)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327666/if-operatornameranka-m-can-we-say-anything-about-operatornamerankaa), but $A$ is a matrix $n\times m$.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(B)$, where $B$ is the square matrix made by padding $A$ with zero rows or zero columns. Then apply the solution in the MSE question you linked.

More explicitly, suppose that $n < m$. Let $\mathbf{0}_{i \times j}$ be the $i \times j$ zero matrix.

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{rank}(AA^t) &= \operatorname{rank}\left(\begin{bmatrix}AA^t&\mathbf{0}_{n \times (m - n)}\\\mathbf{0}_{(m - n) \times n} & \mathbf{0}_{(m - n) \times (m - n)}\end{bmatrix}\right)\\
&= \operatorname{rank}\left(\begin{bmatrix}A\\\mathbf{0}_{(m - n) \times m}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A\\\mathbf{0}_{(m - n) \times m}\end{bmatrix}^t\right)\\
&= \operatorname{rank}\left(\begin{bmatrix}A\\\mathbf{0}_{(m - n) \times m}\end{bmatrix}\right)\\
&= \operatorname{rank}(A).
\end{align}$$

Otherwise, if $n \geq m$, then

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{rank}(AA^t) &= \operatorname{rank}\left(\begin{bmatrix}A&\mathbf{0}_{n \times (n - m)}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A&\mathbf{0}_{n \times (n - m)}\end{bmatrix}^t\right)\\
&= \operatorname{rank}\left(\begin{bmatrix}A&\mathbf{0}_{n \times (n - m)}\end{bmatrix}\right)\\
&= \operatorname{rank}(A).
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what we want to prove is:

For any real-valued matrix **A** (with dimension $n \times m$):   $$\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}})=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top)=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top {\bf{A}})=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}} {\bf{A}}^\top)$$

where ${\bf{A}}^\top$ is the transpose of $\bf{A}$.

To prove this, I'll use a few facts (consider all matrices real-valued):

1. If the matrices B and C are conformal for multiplication, then $\mbox{Rank}({\bf{BC}}) \leq \mbox{Rank}({\bf{B}})$ and $\mbox{Rank}({\bf{BC}}) \leq \mbox{Rank}({\bf{C}})$ ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-prove-and-interpret-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornamemin-ope));
2. $\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}})=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top)$ ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/is-the-rank-of-a-matrix-the-same-of-its-transpose-if-yes-how-can-i-prove-it?rq=1));
3. If **D** and **E** are full-rank square matrices, $\mbox{Rank}({\bf{AD}})=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{EA}})=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}})$ ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801250/rm-rankba-rm-rankb-if-a-in-mathbbrn-times-n-is-invertible?lq=1));
4. If **A** is $n\times m$ with $\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}})=k<\min(n,m)$, then $\exists \,$   **F** with dimension ($n\times k$) and **G** with dimension ($k\times m$) such that **A**=**FG**, and $\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}})=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{F}})=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{G}})=k$ ([proof in page 31, Lemma 4.9](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~iruczins/teaching/cr/cr.intro.pdf))

I'll divide the proof in two parts: 
i) when $\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}})=\min(n,m)$; 
ii) when $\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}})=k<\min(n,m)$

**Proof of i)**

WLOG, suppose that $\min(n,m)=n$, so $\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}})=n$. Therefore, $\bf{A} \bf{A}^\top$ if a full-rank $n \times n$ square matrix. Then we can take $\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top)$ and use fact 3 with **D**=$\bf{A} \bf{A}^\top$:

$$\therefore \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top) = \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top {\bf{D}})=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top {\bf{A}} {\bf{A}^\top}) \leq \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top {\bf{A}}) \leq  \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top)$$

where the inequalities come from fact 1 using **B**=$\bf{A}^\top \bf{A}$ and **C**=$\bf{A}^\top$ for the first one, and **B**=$\bf{A}^\top$, and **C**=$\bf{A}$ for the second one.

From the above, $\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top) \leq \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top {\bf{A}}) \leq  \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top) \implies \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top) = \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top {\bf{A}})$.

Using the same argument, we get that $\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}) \leq \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}} {\bf{A}}^\top) \leq  \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}) \implies \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}) = \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}} {\bf{A}}^\top )$.

From fact 2, $\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}})=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top)$, so the above implies that

$$\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}})=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top)=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top {\bf{A}})=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}} {\bf{A}}^\top) \quad \blacksquare$$

**Proof of ii)**

Now, $\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}})=k<\min(n,m)$. From fact 4, **F** ($n\times k$) has rank $k$, so $\bf{F}^\top \bf{F}$ is full-rank square ($k \times k$). The same  is valid for $\bf{G} \bf{G}^\top$. Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}})=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{F}})=\mbox{Rank}(\underbrace{{\bf{F}} {\bf{G}}}_{={\bf{A}}} {\bf{G}^\top}) = \mbox{Rank}(\bf{A}{\bf{G}^\top} \bf{F}^\top {\bf{F}})&=\mbox{Rank}(\bf{A}{\bf{A}^\top} {\bf{F}}) \\ &\leq \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}{\bf{A}^\top}) \\
&\leq \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}})
\end{align}$$

$$\therefore \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}) \leq \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}{\bf{A}^\top}) \leq \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}) \implies \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}})=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}{\bf{A}^\top})$$

Using a similar argument, we can show that:
$$\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top)=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{G}}^\top) \leq \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top {\bf{A}}) \leq \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top) \implies \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top {\bf{A}}) = \mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top).$$

Hence,

$$\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}})=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top)=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}}^\top {\bf{A}})=\mbox{Rank}({\bf{A}} {\bf{A}}^\top) \quad \blacksquare$$