# Equivalence and rank equivalence

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a [$*$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*-algebra).

Let $P(A)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\{p\in M_n(A):\text {$p$ is a projection} \}$. By projection I mean $p=p^*=p^2$.

Define the an equivalence relation on $P(A)$ by $p \sim q \Leftrightarrow $  there is a rectangle matrix $u$ with entries in $A$ such that $p=u^*u$ and $q=uu^*$.

I wonder why this definition coincides with the rank equivalence in the linear algebra, i.e if $A=\mathbb C$, then $p \sim q$ if and only if they have the same rank.

I think the "only if" part is relatively easier, and the answer follows from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349738/prove-rank-ata-rank-a-for-any-a-m-times-n). But I have trouble this the other direction: given two rectangle matrices of the same rank, why can they be expressed into  $p=u^*u$ and $q=uu^*$? It should follow from a theorem in linear algebra, but what is it? Do we need the hypothesis that $p,q$ are projections?

The source of this question is the Example 7.1.1(page 220) of *Murphy's C*-algebras and operator theory*.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you write "$*-$algebra", with the hyphen inside the math environment, it looks like a minus sign instead of a hyphen.  Contrast these: $$ *-\text{algebra} \qquad \text{versus}\qquad *\text{-algebra} $$

Comment: Are you sure that this is true? Have you tried some simple examples, say $P$ and $Q$ are projections onto the $x$ and $y$ axis in a 2-dimensional complex vector space?

Comment: One thing that you know is if $P:W\to W$ is a projection with $Im(P) = U$ and $Ker(P) = V$ then $W = U \oplus V$ and then you can write $P = AA^*$ where $A$ is the inclusion $U \hookrightarrow W$. But I don't see why if $Q$ is another matrix with the same rank it has to be the case that $Q = A^*A$...

Comment: @JohnMartin For the source of this question, please see Murphy's C*-algebras and operator theory, Example 7.1.1 on page 220

Answer (score 1):

I owe part of following proof to one of my professors.

Assume rank$(p)$=rank$(q)=k \le$ min$(m,n)$.

Since $p,q$ are [projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Canonical_forms), there exist unitary matrices $u,v$, such that

$$p=u^* \begin{pmatrix}I_k&O\\O&O\end{pmatrix}_{m\times m} u,$$ and that $$ q=v^* \begin{pmatrix}I_k&O\\O&O\end{pmatrix}_{n\times n} v . $$

Let $w=\begin{pmatrix}I_k&O\\O&O\end{pmatrix}_{m\times n}$, then it follows that 
$$\begin{pmatrix}I_k&O\\O&O\end{pmatrix}_{m\times m}=ww^*$$

and that

$$\begin{pmatrix}I_k&O\\O&O\end{pmatrix}_{n \times n}=w^*w.$$

Hence, $$p=u^*ww^*u \sim w^*uu^*w=w^*w \sim  ww^*=wvv^*w^*  \sim v^*w^*wv=q$$

So $p\sim q$ by the transitivity of $\sim$. And I used the condition that $p,q$ are projections.