# Invertable normal equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $n\times m$ matrix, where $n \neq m$, without any zero or equal rows.

What conditions on $A$ would guarantee that

$A^T A$ is invertable?

Comment: $A$ having full rank is necessary. I assume also sufficient.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349738/prove-rank-ata-rank-a-for-any-a-m-times-n