# What kind of matrix $B$ can preserve row space of $A$ when their product, like $BA$

Tags: linear-algebra

Ok, I am not very good at linear algebra. But When I read a post:

[Prove $A^T A$ and $A$ have same rank](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349738/prove-rank-ata-rank-a-for-any-a-m-times-n)

which someone try to prove it by using Null space of $A^T A$ and $A$. An idea pops up. For any matrix $A$ with size of $m\times n$, what different between row space of $BA$ and $A$, and more importantly, what kind of $B$ can make sure the row space of $A$ and $BA$ are the same?

Well, if $B$ is an full rank square matrix, no doubt that row space would not change. But the post above shows that when $B=A^T$ the row space would not change either. And here $B$ does not have to be square.

So, can anyone tell me what kind of $B$ will preserve row space of $A$ when $A$ times $B$?

**Thinks, I should say that all matrix are real.**

Comment: If you have read the comment in your attachment, then the statement is not true for complex matrices, it is true only for real matrices.

Comment: The problem would have everything to do with the intersection of the null space of $B$ and the range (columns space) of $A$, would it not? Think about it …

Answer (score 1):

Thinks for  Harald Hanche-Olsen's hint, I figured it out.

Because null space of $BA$ always included in null space of $A$. For preserve row space of $A$, just need to make sure those two null space equal.

$Ax$ are column combinations of $A$, if $A$'s column space dose not contain any vector which perpendicular to B, OR like Harald Hanche-Olsen said, the null space of $B$ and column space of $A$ only intersected at zero vector, then we got it.

Thinks for Harald Hanche-Olsen again. Very good hint.