# Does $\operatorname{rank} {A^T}A = \operatorname{rank} A$ holds when $A$ is matrix over finite field?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, matrix-rank, transpose

It's true when $A$ is a matrix over $\mathbb{R}$, see [Prove rank $A^TA$ = rank $A$ for any $A_{m \times n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349738/prove-rank-ata-rank-a-for-any-a-m-times-n)

Answer (score 5):

How about $A=\pmatrix{1&1\cr1&1}$ over $\Bbb F_2$?

Comment: This generalizes to show that the statement doesn't hold for *any* finite field, or any field of prime characteristic for that matter: The $p \times p$ matrix $A$ with all entries $1$ has rank $1$ but $A^T A = 0$.

Comment: What if $A$ is $m \times n$ and $\operatorname{rank}{A}=n$ ? does it hold ?