# If $A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $m>n$ and $Ker(A)=0$ then $A^TA$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I know from $rank(A)+nullity(A)=n$ that is $rank(A)=rank(A^T)=n$  and  $nullity(A^T) ≠ 0$.Is there any other useful connection to solve this problem?

Comment: What is def(A)??

Comment: Dimension of $N(A)$.My professor use that term to describe a dimension of nullspace.

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana "deficiency", aka nullity

Comment: Rank A is n then it is not possible to have rank of AA^T to be m

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana I corrected mistake.

Comment: You have edited that looks fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ! Use the fact that 
$$RankA+RankB -k<=Rank (AB)<= min (Rank A , Rank B)$$
 Where $A$ is $n×k$ and $B$ is $k×m$ matrix.

It will work surely!

Comment: Can you give me a source of  $RankA+RankB−k<=Rank(AB)$ ?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-show-rank-AB-≥rank-A-+rank-B-−n

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $A^TAv=0$; then also $v^TA^TAv=(Av)^T(Av)=0$, which implies $Av=0$. Since the null space of $A$ is trivial, you're done: $v=0$, so the nullity of $A^TA$ is zero and the rank is full.

Suppose $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x^Tx=0$; this means
$$
x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+x_n^2=0
$$
so $x_1=0, x_2=0,\dots,x_n=0$ and $x=0$. Apply it to $x=Av$.

Comment: $(Av)^T(Av)=0$, which implies $Av=0$ ; please explain this I didn't understand, sir!

Comment: @Abhishek I added the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can define:

$\mathbb{A}_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be the matrix of any linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R^m}$ .So by **Sylvester's law** $rank(A)+nullity(A)=n\implies rank(A)=n$

and we know that $rank(A)=rank(A^TA)$=$n$; [1]: [Prove rank $A^TA$ = rank $A$ for any $A_{m \times n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349738/prove-rank-ata-rank-a-for-any-a-m-times-n)

here , $A^TA$ is $n\times n$ , has full rank.

Therefore , $A^TA$ is invertible.  (Hope it may help you.)