# Guaranteed invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let it be two $m \times n$ matrices: $A$ and $B$, where $m,n \geq2$. 
Rows of these matrices are linearly independent.

So, which matrix is guaranteed invertible:
$AA^T$,
$B^TB$,
$AB^T$,
$A^TB$?

I came to the idea that $A^TB$ and $B^TB$ can't be invertable in case $n>m$. 
But need help with choose between $AB^T$ and $AA^T$

Answer (score 1):

As you have rightly said, $B^TB$ and $A^TB$ need not be invertible. Similarly, $AB^T$ can also be noninvertible. For example, when rows of A and B are orthogonal to each other: 
\begin{equation}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
 \end{bmatrix} \hspace{0.5 cm}B= \begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

However, Rank$\{A\}$=Rank$\{AA^T\}=m.$ Hence, $AA^T$ is invertible. Refer this answer for the proof: [Prove rank $A^TA$ = rank $A$ for any $A_{m \times n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349738/prove-rank-ata-rank-a-for-any-a-m-times-n)