# How do I prove dim($A^t A$)=dim($A$) on proving rank($A^TA$)=rank($A$)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

While I'm studying on Linear Algbera, I was stucked in:

[Prove $\operatorname{rank}A^TA=\operatorname{rank}A$ for any $A\in M_{m \times n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349738/prove-operatornamerankata-operatornameranka-for-any-a-in-m-m-times-n)

I understood what above means, and I am now curious about

Yes, I understood : N($A^TA$)=N($A$)

Then, how can I convince that  rank($A^TA$)=rank($A$)?

In the above question, they say it is by rank-nullity theorem

But in my book, it seems like there is a no rank-nullity theroem, but dimension theorem:

Let $V,W$ be vector spaces, and let $T:V->W$ be linear. If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then

nullity($T$) +rank($T$) = dim($V$)

I thought like:

nullity($A^TA$) + rank($A^TA$) =dim($A^TA$) and

nullity($A$) +rank($A$) = dim($A$) So both of the rank would be the same.

But I think the dimensions of $A^TA$ and $A$ are different.

$A^TA$ becomes ${n \times n}$ matrix and $A$ is ${m \times n}$ matrix so the dimension is different.

Where I was wrong? Or I am misunderstood?

Comment: What's $\operatorname{dim}A$?

Comment: @Gae.S. I meant dimension

Comment: The rank-nullity theorem states that the rank plus nullity equals the number of columns.

Comment: If the "dimension" of an m×n matrix is defined to be n, then indeed m×n and n×n have same dimension and everything works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rank is the maximum number of linearly independent *columns* of $A$, and dim($A$) is the number of *columns* of $A$. Same goes for $A^TA$. Since they both have $n$ columns, the proof you linked is correct.

If you look at $A$ and $A^TA$ as linear transformations, then we have $A: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$, and $A^TA: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$. So the right hand side of the dimension theorem is equal to $n$ for both $A$ and $A^TA$.

Comment: So what you mean is $R^n$ means the dimensions when matrix as a linear transformation above?

Comment: Yes, because $A$ takes vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ as input. It acts on an $n$-dimensional vector ($A^TA$ acts on the same vector, but the image of $A$ and $A^TA$ are in different spaces).

Comment: I now understand clearly. My book said matrix as a linear transformation, I was confused. Thanks a lot.