# Question of Theorem Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Let $A$ a matrix of order $m \times n$ of rank $r$; so there are real numbers $\sigma_1 \geq \ldots \geq \sigma_r  > 0$, a orthonormal basis  $v_1, \ldots , v_n $ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a orthonormal basis  $u_1, \ldots , u_m $ of $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that
$$Av_i = \sigma_i u_i \ \ \ \text{for} \  \ \ i=1, \ldots r \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ Av_i =0 \ \ \text{for} \  \ \ i = r+1, \ldots ,n $$

$$A^Tu_i = \sigma_i v_i \ \ \ \text{for} \  \ \ i=1, \ldots r \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ A^Tu_i =0 \ \ \ \text{for} \ \ \ i = r+1, \ldots ,n .$$

The vectors $v_1, \ldots , v_n $ are autovectors of $A^TA$, $u_1, \ldots u_m$ are autovectors of $AA^T$ and $\sigma_1^2, \ldots, \sigma_1^r$ are nonzero autovalues of  $A^TA$ and $AA^T$.

Proof: Let $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ a orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ formed by autovalues of $A^TA$ and let $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ the autovalues associated. We have that every autovalue of $A^TA$ is not negative.

Assume $v_1, \ldots , v_n$ ordered so that $\lambda_1 \geq \ldots \geq \lambda_n$.

How $r=rank(A)=rank(A^TA)$, we have that
$$ \lambda_1 >0, \ldots ,\lambda_r>0 \ \ \ \text{and } \ \ \ \lambda_{r+1}= \ldots = \lambda_n=0.$$

For $i=1, \ldots r$, we define
$$ \sigma_i = \Vert Av_i \Vert_2 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ u_i = \frac{1}{\sigma_i}Av_i.$$ These conditions imply that

$$ Av_i = \sigma_i u_i, \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \Vert u_i \Vert_2 = 1 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \sigma_i^2= \lambda_i, $$
for $i=1, \ldots,  r$.

Now my question: Why the next equality is true?

If $\lambda_i = 0$, for $i= r+1, \ldots,  n$, so

$$Av_i = \lambda_i v_i = 0v_i = 0.$$

I am sorry for my english.

Comment: In English, they are usually called eigenvectors and eigenvalues (though that is a  German/English portmanteau).

Comment: @user: hence "German/English portmanteau". (Though technically it should be a [compound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics)) since the words are not truncated...)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah ok I've misintepreted the german/english as a dubitative statement! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since rank of $A$ is $r$, we have that null space of $A$ has dimension $n-r$, that is

$$Av_i =   0 \implies A^TAv_i=0$$

and since $A^TA$ has also rank $r$, we have that exactly $n-r$ zero eigenvalues $\lambda_i=0$ exist (counting multiplicity) such that

$$A^TAv_i = \lambda_i v_i =  0$$

Refer also to

- [Prove $\operatorname{rank}A^TA=\operatorname{rank}A$ for any $A\in M_{m \times n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/349738/505767)

Comment: Hi, so sorry but I didn't understand it right, there's a way to explain it better

Comment: I know that null space have that dimension, but why these fact  imply in that equation?

Comment: Refer to [Rank–nullity theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank–nullity_theorem)

Comment: Yes, I agree. But $\lambda_i$ is a eigenvalue of $A^TA$, why is it an eigenvalue of A? why $Av_i=\lambda_i v_i$ ?

Comment: I had misinterpreted your doubt at first. Let me now if now it is clear.