# Please tell me a simple proof for the following equality: $\operatorname{rank} A=\operatorname{rank} A A^T.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, transpose

Please tell me a simple proof for the following equality: $$\operatorname{rank} A=\operatorname{rank} A A^T.$$

I proved the above equality as follows:

I found the following formula in "Linear Algebra" (in Japanese) by Ichiro Satake.

> Let $V, V^{'}$ be finite dimensional vector spaces.
> Let $f:V\to V^{'}$ be a linear mapping.
> Let $W\subset V$ be a subspace.
> Then, $\dim f(W) = \dim W - \dim(f^{-1}(0)\cap W)$.

I know $N(A)\cap C(A^T)=\{0\}$ from Gilbert Strang's book, where $N(A)$ is the nullspace of $m\times n$ matrix $A$ and $C(A^T)$ is the row space of $m\times n$ matrix $A$.

I combined the above two propositions as follows:
$$\dim L_A(C(A^T))=\dim C(A^T)-\dim (N(A)\cap C(A^T)).$$
Since $\dim L_A(C(A^T))=\dim C(A A^T)$ and $\dim (N(A)\cap C(A^T))=0$,  $$\dim C(A A^T)=\dim C(A^T).$$

This means $$\operatorname{rank} A=\operatorname{rank} A A^T.$$
Since $\operatorname{rank} A = \operatorname{rank} A^T$, $$\operatorname{rank} A=\operatorname{rank} A A^T=\operatorname{rank} A^T A.$$

Comment: It helps to know that $A^T$ and $A A^T$ have the same null space. Proof: $A^T z = 0 \implies A A^T z = 0 \implies z^T A A^T z = 0 \implies \| A^T z \|^2 = 0 \implies A^T z = 0$. It follows that $A^T$ and $A A^T$ have the same rank.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/349738/304635

Comment: @littleO Thank you very much for your elegant proof.

Comment: @jlammy Thank you very much for your link.