# Prove that a system $(S)$ is inconsistent

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, systems-of-equations

I've been trying to solve this question for quite a time but I didn't come up with anything.

Let $A = (a_{ij}) \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$ and consider the linear system $(S)$: $AX = B$, where
$B \neq 0$. We suppose that for all $k \in \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$, we have $(a_{1k}, a_{2k}, \dots, a_{mk})B = 0$.

PS: the last product is clearly a vector product.

Comment: Note: the last equation is equivalent to $A^\top B = 0$.

Comment: I don't suppose you'd be studying least squares right about now, would you?

Comment: @SammyBlack , Yeh I know but in what would it help me ?

Comment: @TheoBendit no I don't think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $(a_{1k}, a_{2k}, \dots, a_{mk})B = 0$ is equivalent to $A^TB = 0$, as stated in the comments by Sammy Black. But then we can multiply by $A^T$ on both sides of $AX = B$ giving us $A^TAX = A^TB = 0$, implying that the column-vectors of $X$ are in $\textrm{null}(A^TA)$. 
Now, since $\textrm{null}(A^TA) = \textrm{null}(A)$, see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/349966/832015), we must have that the column-vectors of $X$ are in the nullspace of $A$, thus $0 = AX = B$, which is a contradiction, thus the system must be inconsistent if $B \neq 0$.

Comment: makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the good first answer by @Dragonoverlord3000, here is an intuitive one.

$A X = B$ means $B$ is a linear combination of the column vectors of $A$. (Or, if you prefer, it is in the vector space generated by them).

The last equation means each column vector in $A$ is orthogonal to $B$. This is contradictory with the previous result, if $B$ is not null.

Comment: I thought about this solution which helps to predict the result, however it seemed to me that it was a bit wordy.