# rank(A) = rank($A^t *A$) for a real matrix A: when is this NOT true?

Tags: matrix-rank

I found the proof for

rank($A$) = rank($A^T \cdot A$) , A $\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$

once here, [Prove $\operatorname{rank}A^TA=\operatorname{rank}A$ for any $A\in M_{m \times n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349738/prove-operatornamerankata-operatornameranka-for-any-a-in-m-m-times-n) , and also in the wikipedia entry.

I work with a $3200x10$ matrix $A$ in Matlab which gives me rank($A) = 10$.
However, Matlab return rank($A^T \cdot A)=5$, i.e., rank($A$) $\neq$ rank($A^T \cdot A$).
The entries $A_{ij}$ are in the order of $1e-6$ to $1e-9$.

Is it possible that the matrix is so poorly conditioned that the above relation does not hold, or might there be other reasons?

Comment: The equality always holds, so this is definitely a Matlab issue.

Comment: Yes. But can a badly scaled matrix cause this equation to be violated?

Comment: Mathematically no, numerically yes.