# A proof for a theorem related to rank and matrix product.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For all matrix $\mathbf{M} \in \mathbb{R}^{m,n}$ and $\mathbf{N} \in \mathbb{R}^{n,p}$, the inequality $\operatorname{rank}\mathbf{M} + \operatorname{rank}\mathbf{N} - n \leq \operatorname{rank}(\mathbf{M}\mathbf{N}) \leq \min(\operatorname{rank}\mathbf{M},\operatorname{rank}\mathbf{N})$ holds.
What would be a proof of this theorem?

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269474/prove-that-textrankab-ge-textranka-textrankb-n) and [for the other part](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-prove-and-interpret-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornamemin-ope)

Comment: Here's [another proof of Sylvester's inequality](http://www-m9.ma.tum.de/foswiki/pub/WS2010/IMCSeminar/RankOfMatrix.pdf) (page 3) and [the other part](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Matrix_Multiplication/Solutions) (problem 15).