# Derivation of formula $\mathrm{rank}(A)+\mathrm{rank}(B)-m\le\mathrm{rank}(AB)\le\min\{\mathrm{rank}(A), \mathrm{rank}(B)\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

$T$ is a linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow\Bbb R^m$ and $U:\Bbb R^m\longrightarrow\Bbb R^n$ where $m≠n$ such that $TU$ is bijective. Then where did this formula
$\mathrm{rank}(T)+\mathrm{rank}(U) -m \le \mathrm{rank}(TU) \le \min\{\mathrm{rank}(T), \mathrm{rank}(U)\}$ come from?
Can someone please give its proof?

Comment: I guess you might find a few similar questions if you have a look at questions tagged [matrix-rank+inequality](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matrix-rank+inequality).

Comment: Some posts related to the left inequality: [Sylvester rank inequality: $\operatorname{rank} A + \operatorname{rank}B \leq \operatorname{rank} AB + n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/298836) and [Prove that $\text{rank}(AB)\ge\text{rank}(A)+\text{rank}(B)-n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/269474).

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Note that for any linear map 
   $$T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$$
   the rank of $T$ is less or equal than $\min(n,m)$.
2. A linear map $$T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$
   is bijective iff its rank is $n$.
3. $m\geq n$, due to $1$.
4. The second inequality is standard.

Comment: In point 2, you wrote T:R^n-> R^n, although T:R^n-> R^m. And i dont understand your point 3.Please explain

Answer (score 0):

[This inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties) is known as Sylvester's Rank inequality. The related properties are provided in the above link.